# Maintaining topology on MultiLineString

Tags: leaflet, openlayers, topology, topojson, leaflet-geoman

I'm trying to get topological movement of lines with Leaflet-Geoman plugin using TopoJSON. There is a [method](https://github.com/topojson/topojson-client/blob/master/README.md#mesh) called `topojson.mesh` , which

> Returns the GeoJSON MultiLineString geometry object representing the mesh for the specified object in the given topology. This is useful for rendering strokes in complicated objects efficiently, as edges that are shared by multiple features are only stroked once. If object is not specified, a mesh of the entire topology is returned.

Using an answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57543715/deduplicate-polygon-state-country-shared-boundaries) post, I've been able to return the MultiLineString using `topojson.mesh`. Since [Leaflet-Geoman](https://github.com/geoman-io/leaflet-geoman) supports MultiLineString, I came across with idea that may be the returned mesh can be edited with Leaflet-Geoman while maintaining the topological properties.

But below shows what happens when plugin used with the returned MultiLineString.

[image]

What I need is I need to move below points without breaking the line.

[image]

Is that a doable?

I'll attach the code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Topology Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/leaflet.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@geoman-io/leaflet-geoman-free@latest/dist/leaflet-geoman.css" />

    <style>
        #mapdiv {
            height: 899px;
            background-color: #acd6e2;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="mapdiv"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/topojson@3"></script>
    <script src="src/js/leaflet-src.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@geoman-io/leaflet-geoman-free@latest/dist/leaflet-geoman.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var mymap = L.map('mapdiv', {
            layers: [
                new L.TileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                    'attribution': 'Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                })
            ],
        });

        mymap.pm.addControls({
            position: 'topleft',
            drawCircle: false,
        });


        fetch("data/data.geojson")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(json => {

                //var layer = L.geoJSON(json).addTo(map);
                var topo = topojson.topology([json]);

                console.log(json, topo, topojson.mesh(topo));

                var layerLines = L.geoJson(topojson.mesh(topo), {
                    fill: false,
                }).addTo(mymap);


                mymap.fitBounds(layerLines.getBounds());

            });
    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

The data.geojson

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -113,
              37
            ],
            [
              -113,
              40
            ],
            [
              -109,
              40
            ],
            [
              -109,
              37
            ],
            [
              -113,
              37
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -109,
              37
            ],
            [
              -109,
              39
            ],
            [
              -104,
              39
            ],
            [
              -104,
              37
            ],
            [
              -109,
              37
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -109,
              34
            ],
            [
              -109,
              37
            ],
            [
              -102,
              37
            ],
            [
              -102,
              34
            ],
            [
              -109,
              34
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -104,
              37
            ],
            [
              -104,
              40
            ],
            [
              -100,
              40
            ],
            [
              -100,
              37
            ],
            [
              -104,
              37
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I would say that what you want to achieve is not achievable with Leaflet-Geoman plugin. Yes, it can edit `MultiLineString` geometry, but has no idea that this geometry comes from TopoJSON where certain points should stay together.

Comment: `@TomazicM` Thanks so much. It is an eye opener! I have two questions: 
1) Is there a way I can assure that `topojson.mesh` really returned a mesh.
2) Are there any plugins work with topoJSON

Comment: Ad1: Mesh is just a nickname for MultiLineString that optimally (display execution wise) describes TopoJSON topolgy. Do you trust it that it's is done correctly? As much as any library. Complex software without bugs does not exist. Ad2: I'm not aware of any, except for [leaflet-omnivore](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore) plugin, but this one is just for displaying TopoJSON with Leaflet.

Comment: Forgot to mention one more TopoJSON library: [MapShaper](https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper).

Comment: `@TomazicM` Thanks so much for the explaining through out the problem. I found a [thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13101/how-to-preserve-topology-while-editing-polygons-in-openlayers) here. The [answer](http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/bjornharrtell/eventbasedtopology2/examples/topology.html) is using openlayers. Not sure if this still works or not. I will have to do some research on this. It seems like this methord is using the `openlayers 2`. I'm going to try it out anyway :) – Hashan hemachandra

Comment: `@TomazicM` I was mentioning this answer on the other question I tagged you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who is looking for an answer to this type of question, I found a method using `OpenLayers v6.5.0`. Their is an example for [**Draw and Modify Features**](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-and-modify-features.html), which can maintain the topology of lines and polygons. I will post two examples here.

This one is for LineStrings

[image: Below one is for LineStrings]

This one is for Polygons

[image: Below one is for Polygons]

Hope this helps some one :)